# Why does SUSE Linux not recognize the entire physical RAM?

Tags: linux, memory

We equipped our HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9 computer with 512 Gigabytes (GB) of physical RAM. The computer's BIOS correctly shows that 512 GB of physical memory are installed. But regrettably the operating system, SUSE Linux Enterprise Release 11 Service Pack 4, shows the total memory only with a size of 504.7 GB, which is much smaller than the expected and desired 512 GB. I see the number 504.7 GB for the total memory in the Gnome system monitor, and when I execute the command "free -m" in a terminal session, it displays the total memory with a size of 516780 Megabytes, which corresponds to 504.7 GB. This irritates me because I want to use the complete 512 GB of physical RAM for the software which is running on this server. I do not want to lose 7.3 GB of RAM for nothing. Searching on the Internet did not help me to find out why Linux recognizes only 504.7 GB of total memory instead of the actually installed 512 GB. Moreover, I do not see anything in the computer's BIOS which could explain this strange loss of 7.3 GB RAM. Therefore, I am now asking the experts in this community:
How can I configure the Linux operating system to recognize and use the complete 512 GB of physical memory?

Answer (score 6):

It's frustrating that someone managing a high end server with 512GB of RAM is focused on this.

Run `free -g`.

If the server [POSTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) with 512GB, it means that the RAM is healthy.

The Linux kernel and system BIOS reserve some amount of RAM, and this is normal. It's not a mistake, it's not a scheme intended to rip you off from the amount of RAM you've purchased. It is what it is:

256GB server:

```
#  free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           252        152         99          0          0          2
```

---

Or this 64GB RAM system:

[image]

Comment: It is very doubtful if it is actually true that "the Linux kernel reserves some amount of RAM" and that this leads to the lower number of the displayed total RAM. The man page of the FREE command describes the value of the column "total" as "Total installed memory" (see http://man7.org/linux/man-ages/man1/free.1.html), and "installed memory" usually means the physical RAM. Thus the impression remains that the Linux kernel does not recognize the entire physical RAM correctly. How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: -1 *It's frustrating that someone managing a high end server with 512GB of RAM is focused on this.*  First, it's not a high end server.  I have a rackful of servers with all that, and more, and they're obsolete by modern standards.  (Max memory on G9 Proliant DL380 is 3.0 TiB) Second, this statement detracts from the validity of your answer by injecting emotion and conflict into a technical discourse.

Comment: It's just an everyday thing... Like, anyone who's being around hardware knows this is a given.

Comment: @StevenMuchram My workstation has 24 GiB, and reports 23.5.  Sorry, that's yours and two more reporting a total that is about 95% of the installed total.

Comment: @ewwhite I've been doing this for a minute.  I've recently shifted to working almost exclusively with Linux.  Past Solaris and Windows and Linux experience never exposed me to this quirk..

Comment: @Xalorous "Hardware reserved memory"  At least some portion of your memory is reserved for use at a lower level than the OS - BIOS, hardware, etc, and this applies to Windows, Solaris, BSD, Linux and every other OS out there.  You may not have noticed because of the different ways different OSes report memory use, but it's there.

Answer (score 5):

I don't work with SUSE, but CentOS exhibits similar (or the same) behavior. Usually this has to due with BIOS reservations.

Consider this CentOS 7 system with 8 16GB ECC DIMMs installed.

```
# dmidecode -t 17 | grep Size
    Size: 16384 MB
    Type Detail: Registered (Buffered)
    Size: No Module Installed
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Size: 16384 MB
    Type Detail: Registered (Buffered)
    Size: No Module Installed
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Size: 16384 MB
    Type Detail: Registered (Buffered)
    Size: No Module Installed
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Size: 16384 MB
    Type Detail: Registered (Buffered)
    Size: No Module Installed
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Size: 16384 MB
    Type Detail: Registered (Buffered)
    Size: No Module Installed
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Size: 16384 MB
    Type Detail: Registered (Buffered)
    Size: No Module Installed
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Size: 16384 MB
    Type Detail: Registered (Buffered)
    Size: No Module Installed
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Size: 16384 MB
    Type Detail: Registered (Buffered)
    Size: No Module Installed
    Type Detail: Synchronous
```

That should have 128GB worth of ram. However, CentOS only reports 125GB worth of system memory.

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           125G         65G         56G        113M        4.3G         56G
Swap:          3.8G          0B        3.8G
```

The rest is being revered by the kernel for BIOS/hardware use.

```
# dmesg | grep e820
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000000993ff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000099400-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007de21fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007de22000-0x000000007deb0fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007deb1000-0x000000007dfb9fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007dfba000-0x000000007e1dffff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007e1e0000-0x000000007f364fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007f365000-0x000000007f7fffff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000080000000-0x000000008fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed3ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000207fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x2080000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x80000000-0xffffffff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x7de22 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] e820: [mem 0x90000000-0xfed1bfff] available for PCI devices
[    0.948608] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x00099400-0x0009ffff]
[    0.948610] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x7de22000-0x7fffffff]
```

The only difference between Linux and Windows in representation is that Windows is a little bit clearer on what's going on.

[image: Windows 10 Total vs Usable Memory]

In Linux you'd have to look at `dmesg`.

```
# dmesg | grep Memory
[    0.000000] Memory: 131808356k/136314880k available (6441k kernel code, 2132248k absent, 2374276k reserved, 4265k data, 1620k init)
```

Comment: Thanks 84104, your detailed explanations and examples regarding the DMESG command go well in the direction of what I wanted to know. However, Windows not only displays the RAM usage more clearly than Linux, it also seems to handle the available physical RAM more economically. For example, on one of our HP servers with 128 GB physical RAM, Windows Server 2012 displays the following in the Control Panel: "Installed memory (RAM): 128 GB (128 GB usable)" - yes, it really displays "128 GB usable". Thus, while Linux somehow reserves or hides around 3 GB of 128 GB RAM, Windows does not do this.

Answer (score -2):

<del>POST may show 512 GB installed, but BIOS is likely flagging several pages unusable due to errors in the RAM. You need to consult with your hardware vendor to diagnose your RAM, and possibly open a case for replacement of faulty RAM.</del>

If RAM is shown bad in POST/BIOS, you should run onboard diagnostics.  If they show bad RDIMMS, contact HP.

Comment: The HP RAM is all-or-nothing. If the OP was missing 32GB or RAM, that would indicate a problem. This issue here is just misunderstanding.

Comment: The BIOS shows a table titled "Memory details", and in this table each memory module is explicitly listed with the status "Good, in use". Therefore, there is no reason to believe that any of the RAM modules has a physical error. Rather, the available information in the BIOS indicates that all RAM modules are correctly functional.

Comment: Your OS is using some - have you asked on SuSE specific sites?

Comment: @StevenMuchram I just checked on a RHEL system.  23.5 GiB total memory for the system.  ewwhite is right that Linux is reserving the memory.  I would agree that the 'total memory' should show the GiB installed.  The reserved memory should show as 'reserved', 'in-use', or 'unavailable'.

Comment: @Xalorous: Yes, indeed the "total" column of the display of the FREE command should show the entire amount of installed physical RAM. The man page of the FREE command even describes the "total" column as showing the "Total installed memory", which generally means the installed physical RAM (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html). Do you know any official documentation which explicitly deals with this topic? If the Linux kernel "reserves" several Gigabytes of memory, it should display this openly.

Comment: If `free` is part of the OS, not the kernel, then as far as the OS is concerned, only the part that the kernel makes available is installed.  Otherwise, the documentation for one command shows different terminology from what we expect to see.  I guess this is to be expected from open source project.  It is a downside, IMO.

Comment: In the current context, no virtualization is involved; rather, the Linux operating system was installed simply directly on the computer. Therefore, the FREE command should show the "Total installed memory" as 512 GB.